# How to set iframe height based on content from cross domain?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, height

Been searching everywhere for a solution to this. How can you set the iframe height to the size of the iframe content when the content is from another domain? I'm using the following javascript but I get the `permission denied to access property 'document'` because the iframe content is from another domain.

```
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
        if(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight < 500) {
          iframe.height = "500px";
        } else {
          iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
  }

<iframe name="myiframe" id="myiframe" onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)...
```

I've read up on a few hacks but they all include using a second javascript file added to the iframe to send a postMessage back to the parent. However this isnt really much of a solution because for cross domain content you don't have them sort of privileges to go round adding javascript files to their servers.

Any one have any suggestions or alternative solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this without iframe sending messages to your parent page. It's a security feature to prevent cross domain content modifications. Because if you can access `document` of cross-domain iframe, you can change pretty much anything on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read up on a few hacks but they all include using a second javascript file added to the iframe to send a postMessage back to the parent.

Yes, that's the solution.

> However this isnt really much of a solution because for cross domain content you don't have them sort of privileges to go round adding javascript files to their servers.

If you don't have a good enough relationship with the other website for them to help you find out how tall a page is when they send it to one of your mutual visitors, then you simply can't do it.

To find out the height of the page, you need access to the DOM.

If you have access to the DOM, you have access to the content of the DOM.

If you have access to the content of the DOM, you can send the user's browser off to any old site (say, for example, an corporate intranet with personnel records) and copy the data to your site.

This would be a massive security hole, which is why you need the explicit cooperation of the other site.